# Laravel: Populating a Dropdown from DB

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am a newbie to Laravel. I have an issue with a "Variable not found" when I try to populate a DropDown from a Table: The Table Name is Cats (Categories), the Model Name is "Cat" and looks like this:

```
class Cat extends Model
{
     public function project() {

     return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
}


}
```

A Project can have 1 Category. A Category Name can be in multiple projects. I now want to populate a dropdown in a form where I want to insert a new project: To achieve this,

I have made a route:

```
Route::get('myform', 'HomeController@myform');
```

I have made a Function inside my HomeController, where I pass (I do think so) the variable "$cats" to my view:

```
public function myform()
{
$cats = Cat::pluck('name', 'id');
return view('project-insert', get_defined_vars());
}
```

or a different version:

```
public function myform()
{
$cats = Cat::pluck('name', 'id');
return view('project-insert',compact('cats'));
}
```

In my View, I am trying to print out the data with:

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
{!! Form::select('id', $cats, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

But I get a "variable cats not found" error. How can I tell the view to get the variable "$cats"?

I have made a new view (myform.blade.php) and tried the same there:

```
 <html>
 <body>

   {{ dd($cats) }}

   {!! Form::open() !!}

       {!! Form::select('id', $cats, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

   {!! Form::close() !!}

 </body>
</html>
```

and a route:

```
 Route::get('myform', 'HomeController@myform');
```

linked in my Controller to the new View:

```
 public function myform() { 
   $user = Auth::user(); 
   $cats = Cat::pluck('name', 'id'); 
   return view('myform', get_defined_vars()); 
 }
```

And now:

```
 dd($cats)
```

is showing the desired result... Strange, that it is working on the new blade, and not on the old one!

Thank you for your help and advice!

Stefan

Comment: Although using `compact('cats')` is more expressive and I'd encourage you to use it over `get_defined_vars()`, both of these ways should work. Can you try to pinpoint where exactly you get the error? If you remove the `{!! Form::select(...) !!}` line, do you still get the error?

Comment: Hi Devk, thank you for your assistance. I have made a new blade: my form.blade.php with that code:

Comment: The code is really messy to look at in the comment, maybe you can edit your original question and add it.

Comment: Dear Devk, sorry for that inconvenience. I have edited the code above.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere else. Where else in this request cycle are you using the `$cats` variable? Also, does the error say anything other than `variable cats not found`? `storage/logs/laravel.log` file might have more descriptive explanation (depending on your logging settings).

Comment: 1question, does your controller has auth middleware? because in your second function which you claim it works you have `$user = Auth::user(); ` but in first function you don&#39;t. maybe try add that to your first function in order to validate auth user as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return view('project-insert', ['cats' => $cats]);
```

But `compact` and `get_defined_vars` is same. 
You can try to add before `{!! Form::open() !!}` this:
`{{ dd($cats }}`

Comment: Dear J. Doe. Thank you for your assistance. When I remove the Form, and try to print out using {{ dd($cats) }} the variable $cats is still not present. When I create a new view, and link to that view from the "myform function", everything is working fine. Strange behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

my mistake. The Problem occurs because of a wrong route in the

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('project-insert') }}">
```

The Route had to be:

```
Route::post('project-insert', 'ProjectController@insert')->name('project-insert');
```

instead of

```
Route::post('project-insert', 'ProjectController@insert');
```

Sorry for confusing :-(

Kind Regards,

Stefan